# Unable to place intro.js on element by ID

Tags: javascript, intro.js

This is my code:

```
<div class='introduction' id="qqq">
  <div class="dummy" data-step="1" data-intro="It's a nice Saturday afternoon">
    <p>Today</p>
  </div>
</div>

introJs("#qqq").start();
```

Result: Something else in the ether will be highlighted and the tooltip is displayed.

If I fire it like `introJs().start()` or `introJs().goToStepNumber(1).start()`, it works, but I need to control when to fire it.

Comment: when do you want to fire it?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: Because it's not clear what is wrong with when you're firing it currently or how using different code would change _when_ the code is fired.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use the data attributes then you need to fire the DIV that has those attributes.

In your example I would move the data attributes to the `#qqq` DIV:

```
<div class='introduction' id="qqq" data-step="1" data-intro="It's a nice Saturday afternoon">
  <div class="dummy">
    <p>Today</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>introJs("#qqq").start();</script>
```

Comment: Did that answer help you @erdomester?